# sort_by broken in pandas >= 0.18.0?

Tags: python, pandas

I start with a data frame like

```
print(df)
                   int          float  _i
1                    2   2.000000e+00   1
3                    3   3.000000e+00   3
2                    3   4.000000e+00   2
4 -9223372036854775808 -1.797693e+308   4
0 -9223372036854775808   1.000000e+00   0
```

If I use `sort_values` to sort by two columns I get the output you see below. So `sort_values` seems to do nothing. If I only one column name it works, and the way I use it worked in previous pandas versions. Is there any change in pandas I'm not aware of ?

```
print(df.sort_values(["int", "float"]))
                   int          float  _i
1                    2   2.000000e+00   1
3                    3   3.000000e+00   3
2                    3   4.000000e+00   2
4 -9223372036854775808 -1.797693e+308   4
0 -9223372036854775808   1.000000e+00   0
```

In pandas `0.17.0` I get:

```
print(df.sort_values(["int", "float"]))
                   int          float  _i
4 -9223372036854775808 -1.797693e+308   4
0 -9223372036854775808   1.000000e+00   0
1                    2   2.000000e+00   1
3                    3   3.000000e+00   3
2                    3   4.000000e+00   2
```

Comment: In addition to this, apparently if you interchange the two column names, you get two different o/ps (`v0.19.1`)

Comment: I'm seeing this with 0.18.1 too.

Comment: OK, I see the problem, it looks like the large negative int value is throwing off the sorting mechanism, sorting on the float column works correctly and as expected

Comment: It works as expected for `df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [4,2,3,3,-10, -1], 'b':[3,2,4,3,2,-1]})`. As @EdChum points out, it's a problem with the large absolute values.

Comment: If this helps: I used the minimal value of `int64` here.

Comment: Can you post an [issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues) as this is a bug, it looks like when you have mixes dtypes then the sorting fails, when you have a series with the same numerical values then it works fine

Comment: `df.sort_values('int')` works OK for me on 0.18.0, but I have the same problem as you all with `df.sort_values(["int", "float"])`

Comment: @EdChum I'm not sure it's mixed dtypes.  For example, I still get the wrong answer with `df.astype(np.int64).sort_values(['int','float'])`.  So from my limited testing it seems to be a problem with passing a list (2 or more values to sort) vs passing a single variable (which seems to work fine for me)

Comment: @JohnE Yes I see the same problem with 2 columns of int64, this seems like a basic bug and unclear why it's a problem

Comment: Bug report here: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/14922

Comment: Fixed here: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/commit/6bea8275e504a594ac4fee71b5c941fb520c8b1a

Comment: @rocksportrocker  can you please put that link as an answer to this question?  I.e. answer your own question.  That will allow this question to be marked as answered (it's currently one of the highest ranked pandas questions on the "unanswered" tab)

Comment: Seems this question, or at least the title is no longer correct as the issue was fixed, and sorting works properly in pandas > 0.20.0

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the bug was fixed by python/pandas. It is no longer a bug. This question can be closed.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the reported bug was fixed a while ago

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recent pandas versions don't show this bug anymore, was fixed a while ago:  https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/commit/6bea8275e504a594ac4fee71b5c941fb520c8b1a

Answer (score -1):

I'm able to get the sorting you desire for your case by calling the sort as follows:

```
print(df.sort_values(by=["int", "float"], na_position='first'))

                   int          float  _i
3 -9223372036854775808 -1.797693e+308   4
4 -9223372036854775808   1.000000e+00   0
0                    2   2.000000e+00   1
1                    3   3.000000e+00   3
2                    3   4.000000e+00   2
```

However, I'm not sure why the sorting is behaving different between the two versions. I checked the GitHub source code and I didn't see any changes to the sort_values function between those two versions. It could be that something deeper in the code has changed.

Code that does sorting:

```
2968                if len(by) > 1:
2968                from pandas.core.groupby import _lexsort_indexer
2969    
2970                def trans(v):
2971                    if com.needs_i8_conversion(v):
2972                        return v.view('i8')
2973                    return v
2974                keys = []
2975                for x in by:
2976                    k = self[x].values
2977                    if k.ndim == 2:
2978                        raise ValueError('Cannot sort by duplicate column %s' % str(x))
2979                    keys.append(trans(k))
2980                indexer = _lexsort_indexer(keys, orders=ascending,
2981                                           na_position=na_position)
2982                indexer = com._ensure_platform_int(indexer)

3004        new_data = self._data.take(indexer, axis=self._get_block_manager_axis(axis),
3005                                       convert=False, verify=False)
```

Something with _lexsort_indexer() or self._data.take() may have changed.

Comment: I committed a bug fix to pandas already. And for some reasons the value 9223372036854775808 which is the smallest 64 bit int is/was treated as "missing value". I assume this was done when implementing the datetime64 datatype, where this specific value is officially named "NaT" (not a time) similar to "NaN" for float.

Comment: Here is the fix: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/commit/6bea8275e504a594ac4fee71b5c941fb520c8b1a

Comment: You're fast! Thank you!